# The best place to store large data retrieved by a java servlet (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jndi

I have the java servlet that retrieves data from a mysql database. In order to minimize roundtrips to the database, it is retrieved only once in init() method, and is placed to a HashMap<> (i.e. cached in memory).

For now, this HashMap is a member of the servlet class. I need not only store this data but also *update* some values (counters in fact) in the cached objects of underlying hashmap value class. And there is a Timer (or Cron task) to schedule dumping these counters to DB.

So, after googling i found 3 options of storing the cached data:

1) as now, as a **member of servlet class** (but servlets can be taken out of service and put back into service by the container at will. Then the data will be lost)

2) in **ServletContext** (am i right that it is recommended to store small amounts of data here?)

3) in a **JNDI resource**.

What is the most preferred way?

Answer (score 5):

Put it in `ServletContext` But use `ConcurrentHashMap` to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: JNDI is going to depend on the provider, and is most likely *not* identical. But as a member of the `Servlet` or in the `ServletContext`, makes no difference storage-wise, only in how it can be accessed.

Comment: @ericson - storage-wise, yes. But as it's not identical due to the remark of the OP, I removed that part :)

Answer (score 3):

From those 3 options, the best is to store it in the application scope. I.e. use [`ServletContext#setAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). You'd like to use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) for this. In normal servlets you can access the `ServletContext` by the inherited `getServletContext()` method. In JSP you can access it by `${attributename}`.

If the data is getting excessive large that it eats too much of Java's memory, then you should consider a 4th option: use a cache manager.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious way would be use something like ehcache and store the data in that. ehcache is a cache manager that works much like a hash map except the cache manager can be tweaked to hold things in memory, move them to disk, flush them, even write them into a database via a plugin etc. Depends if the objects are serializable, and whether your app can cope without data (i.e. make another round trip if necessary) but I would trust a cache manager to do a better job of it than a hand rolled solution.

Comment: Might not be the most "obvious," but it's quite sensible.

Comment: It can also deal with the "warming up" i.e. reading from mysql, and the background updating. Takes a fair bit of reading, but it would be super clean in the application code.

Answer (score 1):

If your cache can become large enough and you access it often it'll be reasonable to utilize some caching solution. For example ehcache is a good candidate and easily integrated with Spring applications, too. Documentation is [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation).

Also check [this overview](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions) of open-source caching solutions for Java.